# BiodiversityR and Rcmdr Issues in Mac

Tags: r

I am attempting (repeatedly) to load BiodiversityR, which automatically loads Rcmdr.  BiodiversityR loads fine, according to my Rstudio window, but when it attempts to load Rcmdr, it gives me the following error message:

> Loading required package: Rcmdr
>
> Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'Rcmdr', details:
>
> call: data(dune)
>
> error: object 'dune' not found
>
> Error: package 'Rcmdr' could not be loaded

I am working on a MacBook, using OSX 10.6.8.  I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Rcmdr and RcmdrMisc, loading a bunch of Rcmdr plug-ins, and updating all installed packages that BiodiversityR and Rcmdr rely on (including vegan), to no avail.  I've also restarted R, tried using R instead of Rstudio, etc.  Any help on this is much appreciated.

Cecilia Hennessy LaBonte

Purdue University

Comment: Do you have the same error when you type `library(Rcmdr)` in the R console?

Comment: UPDATE: a friend told me to clear my history in R and retry.  In Rstudio, I went to "session" and "clear workspace".  After that, the BiodiversityR and Rcmdr loaded, no problem!  :)

I hope this can help someone that's new to R, like me!

Comment: Marat, I had the same problem when doing what you suggest.  No problems after clearing workspace, however!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, and here's how I finally managed to install `Rcmdr` on my mac (R 3.5.1):

1 -

```
install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
                 repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")

library('data.table')

install.packages('car')

library('car')
```

2 - Install: https://www.xquartz.org/ (XQuartz-2.7.11.dmg)

3 - Logout & login again. (or restart your Mac), and:

```
install.packages('Rcmdr')
```

4 - Confirm installation of the missing packages that will be asked to install.

5 - Launch it:

```
library('Rcmdr')
```

I hope it can help!